# list(map(some code)) and map(some code) do not make a difference

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def ask_for_two_floats(question):
    """
    Asks user to input two floats separated by space bar. The input is asked
    until user gives two suitable inputs. Inputs are returned as floats.
    """
    while True:
        try:
            x, y = map(float, input(question).split())
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter two floats separated by space. ")
            continue
        break
    return x, y

print(ask_for_two_floats("Give me two numbers: "))
```

My question is, why do many people write list( in front of map funtion? If i write:

```
x, y = list(map(float, input(question).split()))
```

the output and the way the function works do not change. The output is always a tuple. So why write the map function inside list() if it does not make any difference? And if I want this program to return a list containing x and y like so: [x, y], how should I change my code?

Comment: It does not make a significant difference *in your case*. That is not the same as it not making a difference in general. Replace ``x, y`` with just ``result`` and see what changes...

Answer (score 3):

For the first question, the reason you see no difference is because you are unpacking the `map` object into two separate variables. Note that `map` returns a generator, not a list, and so conversion to a list requires `list()`.

For example,

```
>>> type(map(int, "123"))
<class 'map'>
>>> map(int, "123")
<map object at 0x00000203276D9C08>
>>> list(map(int, "123"))
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x, y, z = map(int, "123")
>>> x, y, z
(1, 2, 3)
>>> a, b, c = list(map(int, "123"))
>>> a, b, c
(1, 2, 3)
```

As for the second question, in order to return `[x,y]`, simply write `[x,y]` in place of `x,y` in the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

> So why write the map function inside list() if it does not make any
>   difference?

What you are going to do is to split a string and convert tokens to floating point numbers. Basically map function takes an iterable object and calls a specific function for each element. But map returns a generator, not a list.

Once again if you want to return a list, you don't need to unpack anything, just return list(map(...)). Or if you need these variables throughout your function, use a plain list initializer like so [x, y]